# SAP Crystal Report for Visual Studio runtime licensing

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Since CR for Visual Studio free license and
CR for Visual Studio SP33 CR Runtime is able to be installed in server without VS.

Because the company server didn't have Visual Studio installed, and I want to deploy the C# ASP.NET web application into the server; which is able to export pdf by utilizing the CR runtime engine.

I want to ask
is **CR for Visual Studio SP33 CR Runtime.msi file free licensing within company use**?

Answer (score 0):

The scope of its use and the distribution method is important.  If the report is part of a client application, the licensing is free for both internal use and when distributed to 3rd parties as part of the application package.  If the report is part of a server hosted application where multiple users have access to the application, its free for internal use, but requires the application developer to purchase a license for each 3rd party deployment or an OEM contract.  If the report is part of a Commercial Hosting Service, then you will need an OEM contract for both internal use and 3rd party use.

Here's a [link](https://www.sap.com/documents/2015/07/368edae4-597c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.html) to the document from SAP that covers this.  Most of what you need is on the first 4 pages of the document.  It probably wouldn't be a bad idea to talk to someone at SAP about this in more detail though if you want to ensure you have the correct stance on licensing before you begin distribution of any applications outside of your own personal use or internal business use.